# how to implement a searchbar above the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

sorry i'm still getting into swift， and i'm building an app with a search-for-keywords feature, but i couldn't figure it out how to implement a search bar above a keyboard like the picture below:

[this picture is from an app called "Developer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvbCJ.jpg)

i'm thinking of that adding a toolbar with searchbar inside to the keyboard might be a solution, is there any other ways to make this thing works?
sorry for my bad english....

Comment: You need to implement `inputAccessoryView` of a `UITextField`/`UITextView`. It's up to you what to put there, but a `UISearchBar` might be a good idea.

Comment: and there's a thing, the inputAccessryView is pop out when the "search icon" button I clicked. is there anyway to make that happen?